# Distinguish UISwipe gesture over NSTouches

Tags: ios, drawrect, uiswipegesturerecognizer, touches

I have a view where a user can draw things using his fingers on iPad.
He can use 1 - 4 fingers for drawing anything.
I am drawing with the help of NSTouches.
Now client wants me to add a swipe gesture to present a hidden menu.
Is this thing achievable and if yes then how ?

Comment: add `UIGestureRecogniser` to your view and set `delaystouchesBegan=NO`.

Comment: wouldn't this distract drawing ? it does and the touches begin to miss from drawing...

Answer (score 0):

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];  // MENTION WHAT YOU WANT TO DO IN rightSwipeHandle METHOD WHEN SWIPED RIGHT
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];  // YOU CAN INCREASE THE NUMBER OF TOUCHES 
//add the your gestureRecognizer , where to detect the touch..
[listView1 addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];  // MENTION WHAT YOU WANT TO DO IN leftSwipeHandle METHOD WHEN SWIPED RIGHT
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[listView1 addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(upSwipeHandle:)];  // MENTION WHAT YOU WANT TO DO IN upSwipeHandle METHOD WHEN SWIPED RIGHT
upRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[upRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[listView1 addGestureRecognizer:upRecognizer];
[upRecognizer release];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *downRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(downSwipeHandle:)];  // MENTION WHAT YOU WANT TO DO IN downSwipeHandle METHOD WHEN SWIPED RIGHT
downRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[downRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[listView1 addGestureRecognizer:downRecognizer];
[downRecognizer release];
```

Comment: the problem statement is not how to apply swipe gestures... please read again